# How do useCapture eventListener behaves for mozilla and chrome or any old browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How do "useCapture" event listener behaves for mozilla and chrome or any old browswer, if i don't pass the third param as false, will it effect my app.

document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClickOutsideOption);

Comment: It defaults to `false`. So, no?

Comment: The third parameter is optional,,If it is not specified, it defaults to false

Comment: How "old" are you concerned about? The [mdn page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) gives the following note: _"Note: useCapture has not always been optional. Ideally, you should include it for the widest possible browser compatibility."_